# Making config file for shell script

Tags: linux, shell

How do I create the configuration file for our executable shell script?

Comment: Could you elaborate in what do you need and what have you tried?

Comment: ... and which shell are you using.

Comment: I need to create the configuration file for mail notification in shell script.i have a code for sending mail in shell script . how to organize them as config file

Answer (score 3):

Your question is ambiguous, but typically config files for a shell script just contain assignments:

```
$ cat config
FOO=foo-value
$ cat script
#!/bin/sh
test -r ${CONFIG:=/path/to/config} && . $CONFIG
echo The configged value of FOO is ${FOO?FOO is unassigned}
```